# Asyncio with two loops, best practice

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio

I have two infinite loops. Their processing is lightweight. I don't want them to block each other. Is using  `await asyncio.sleep(0)` a good practice?

This is my code

```
import asyncio

async def loop1():
    while True:
        print("loop1")
        # pull data from kafka
        await asyncio.sleep(0)


async def loop2():
    while True:
        print("loop2")
        # send data to all clients using asyncio stream api
        await asyncio.sleep(0)


async def main():
    await asyncio.gather(loop1(), loop2())


asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: Do your coroutines actually do anything with asyncio? If not, threads (I/O) or processes (CPU) may be a better solution.

Comment: Yes, loop1 pulls data from kafka using aiokafka and loop2 sends this data through socket with the asyncio stream API. Maybe lightweight processing was not the right description

Answer (score 1):

Two (many more) `asyncio` tasks will not block each other until one of tasks have some long sync operation inside.

Both of your tasks have only network operations inside (Kafka and API requests), so none of them will block another task.

When should you use `asyncio.sleep(0)`?

Imagine you have some long sync operation - calculations. Calculations is not I/O operation.

This example is more like good to know, if you have such operations in real app, you have to move them in `loop.run_in_executor` and use `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor` as executor. The example:

```py
import asyncio


async def long_calc():
    """
    Some Heavy CPU bound task.
    Better make it sync function and move to ProcessPoolExecutor
    """
    s = 0

    for _ in range(100):
        for i in range(1_000_000):
            s += i**2

        # comment the line and watch result
        # you'll get no working messages
        # that's why I use sleep(0.0) here
        await asyncio.sleep(0.0)

    return s


async def pinger():
    """Task which shows that app is alive"""
    n = 0
    
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        print(f"Working {n}")
        n += 1


async def amain():
    """Main async function  in this app"""
    # run in asyncio.create_task since we want the task
    # to run in parallel with long_calc +
    # we do not want to wait till it will be finished
    # If it were thread it would be called daemon thread
    asyncio.create_task(pinger())
    # await results of long task
    s = await long_calc()
    print(f"Done: {s}")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(amain())
```

If you need me to provide you with `run_in_executor` example - let me know.

Comment: But the "while" in my function could (and I think it does) take all the CPU time if my IO tasks are super reactive?  I guess the point is to assume there is an "await" keyword in loop1 and loop2 for my IO tasks, in that case, the event loop knows to switch the task, right?

Comment: @nicolascarrara It is not the problem of the fact that you use `while` in your async tasks, the potential problem is what you have inside the `while` loop. If you have IO async ops in the tasks - everything is fine, loop switch from one task to another. If you have CPU bound tasks - it is a problem. More information and working example in my answer.